# Substitute s for cos u and ds for -sin u

Tags: real-numbers

Can someone explain why when going from this step:

$$\frac23\int \frac{\sin u}{\cos u}du$$

where substituting $s=\cos u$ and $ds = -\sin u\,du$ produces

$$\frac23\int -\frac1s ds$$

My work shows it to be this from the substitution of $s$ for $\cos u$ and $ds = -\sin u\,du$

$$\frac23 \int \frac{(\sin u)(-\sin u)}{s}ds= \frac23 \int -\frac{\sin^2 u}{s}ds$$

Im not sure how it is correctly reduced to $-1$.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but I would think that, if you are taking a course in which you are expected to do a problem like this, you must have taken a trigonometry course previously.  And one of the most basic "trig identities" is "$sin^2(\theta)+ cos^2(\theta)= 1$" from which $sin^2(\theta)= 1- cos^2(\theta)$.

Comment: Notice that $ds=-\sin u  du$, so $du=\frac{-ds}{\sin u}$

Comment: I have considered that. But even still, if we substitute  -(1-cos^ u) for -sin u, it would appear as 2/3  ∫ (1-cos ^2 u(-sinu))/ (s)  ds, this is still not -1/s. If we distribute ds --> (-sinu - cos^2u) / s  =/= -1/s

Comment: That, perhaps, is not exactly what you are asking.  You say you have $\frac{2}{3}\int \frac{sin(u)}{cos(u)}du$.  Yes, if you let $s= cos(u)$ then $ds= -sin(u)du$.  So $\frac{sin(u) du}{cos(u}= \frac{ds}{-s}$.  You seem to have left "cos(u)" in the numerator instead of using it with "cos(u)du
.   You could also think "since $-sin(u)du= ds$ then $du= -\frac{1}{sin(u)}ds$.  So \frac{sin(u)}{cos(u)}du= \frac{sin(u)}{s}\left(-\frac{1}{sin(u)} ds= -\frac{1}{s}ds$  That is you do not have those two "sin(u)"s multiplying.  One is in the denominator so they cancel.

Comment: When you've $\int \frac{f'(u)}{f(u)}du$, using the substitution $s=f(u)$ one has using the rule $d(f(u))=f'(u)du$ (that holds for good functions), that $1\cdot ds=d(s)=d(f(u))=f'(u)du$ and you can deduce $$\int \frac{1}{f(u)}f'(u)du=\int \frac{1}{s}ds$$ Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

So you have:

$$I=\frac23\int{\frac{\sin{u}}{\cos{u}}d{u}}$$

Let:

$$ s=\cos{u}$$

Therefore:
$$ d{s}=-\sin{u}\  d{u}$$

Now $\cos{u}$ is in the denominator so:
$$I=\frac23\int-\frac{d{s}}{s}$$

Comment: ds = -sin s du or ds = -sin u du?

Comment: Oops, that latter of course - edited answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You have$$I=\int\frac{\sin u}{\cos u}\,\mathrm du$$$$s=\cos u$$$$\mathrm ds=-\sin u \,\mathrm du$$So$$\implies I=\int\frac{\sin u}{\cos u}\,\mathrm du=\int-\frac{-\sin u\,\mathrm du}{\cos u}=\int-\frac{\mathrm ds}{s}=\int-\frac1s\,\mathrm ds$$